# Advanced array sorting

Tags: php, arrays

If I have an array that looks like this:

```
$members = array(
array(
    'id'=>2,
    'name' => 'Bob',
    'status' => 1
    ),
array(
    'id'=>4,
    'name' => 'Fred',
    'status' => 1
    ),
array(
    'id'=>5,
    'name' => 'Sally',
    'status' => 0
    ),
array(
    'id'=>1,
    'name' => 'Fred',
    'status' => 1
    ),
array(
    'id'=>3,
    'name' => 'Jane',
    'status' => 0
    ),
);
```

How can I sort the entries so that they show in alphabetical order by name?

Answer (score 0):

You can define an own comparison function:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}

usort($myarray, "cmp");
```

More about sorting in PHP can be found in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/usort)

Answer (score 0):

Here we are using `usort` and `strcmp` for sorting a nested array. with `strcmp` we are comparing two strings.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780336)

```
$array = array(
array(
    'id'=>2,
    'name' => 'Bob',
    'status' => 1
    ),
array(
    'id'=>4,
    'name' => 'Fred',
    'status' => 1
    ),
array(
    'id'=>5,
    'name' => 'Sally',
    'status' => 0
    ),
array(
    'id'=>1,
    'name' => 'Fred',
    'status' => 1
    ),
array(
    'id'=>3,
    'name' => 'Jane',
    'status' => 0
    ),
);

usort($array, function($data1,$data2){
    return strcmp($data1["name"], $data2["name"]);
});
print_r($array);
```